# Error De Sintaxis Python

Tags: python

Hola muy buenas tengo un error de sintaxis en python no se por que me lo da el codigo es:

def el_resultado():

```
global resultado
global operacion
global contador_resta
global contador_multi
global contador_divi

if operacion=="suma":
    NumeroPantalla.set(resultado+float(NumeroPantalla.get()))
    resultado=0.0
elif operacion=="resta":
    NumeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)-float(NumeroPantalla.get()))
    resultado=0.0
    contador_resta=0
elif operacion=="mult":
    NumeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)*float(NumeroPantalla.get()))
    resultado=0.0
    contador_multi=0
elif operacion=="division":
    try:
        NumeroPantalla.set(float(resultado)/float(NumeroPantalla.get()))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        NumeroPantalla.set("ERROR NO SE PUEDE DIVIR POR 0")
        clear()
    resultado=0.0
    contador_divi=0
```

Me da el erro en el try adjunto una imagen de igual manera 
Soy un poco nuevo en esto, el compilador es visual code
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se trata de un error en la tabulación.

Comment: Verifica que en todas las líneas usas el mismo tipo de indentación (preferiblemente espacios). En Visual Studio Code puedes hacer que te muestre los caracteres invisibles con Mayus+Ctrl+P y luego el comando "Toggle Render Whitespace"

Comment: Si lo he revisado y no hay espacios de hecho si pongo Numeropantalla.set("..") en la linea donde esta el try El programa me funciona pero al poner el try o un simple print me sale ese error

Comment: Y sin embargo en la captura de pantalla que adjuntas se ve una marquita roja justo al inicio de la línea 143, como que el "linter" está detectando un problema justo ahí, ¿seguro que no hay ahí un espacio o quizás otro carácter invisible? Yo borraría la línea del `try:`, pondría el cursor al final de la anterior y pulsaría Intro, dejando que el editor auto-indente la línea siguiente, para escribir de nuevo el `try:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He copiado el código que has pegado al inicio de tu pregunta. Para ello he tenido que darle a la opción "Editar" de la pregunta para así tener acceso a lo que realmente pegaste (y no a la versión reformateada en Markdown por StackOverflow).

Tras seleccionar tu código y copiarlo con Ctrl+C, he abierto Visual Studio Code y lo he pegado con Ctrl+V. El aspecto era normal, pero...

Entonces he activado la opción  "Toggle Render Whitespace" y ha aparecido lo siguiente:

[image: Imagen]

Donde puede verse claramente que casi todas las líneas usan tabuladores para su identado (las flechitas), excepto las líneas 21--25, en las que se usan espacios (los puntitos), e incluso un mix de tabuladores y espacios en la línea 22. **Ese era el problema**

Tienes que convertirlo todo en espacios, para lo que puedes usar Mayus-Ctrl-P y luego el comando "Convert indentation to spaces".

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo  realmente soy nuevo en esto gracias de nuevo por solucionarlo